# Can I make an email template in outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

Most of emails I send are for jobs, so I have to type the subject and attach my resume from the cloud and send it every time, the only difference is the **To** field.

Can I create a template in Outlook that has a subject and my resume attached to it, for reusing?

Comment: It is safe to assume, If you cannot easily find the feature yourself and your unable to find any documentation in the Outlook.com help articles, this feature does not exist for Outlook..com.  if you need this feature use a desktop email client instead.

Comment: Please read the outlook.com tag. You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

You can make template on outlook

Check  [Create an email message template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-email-message-template-43ec7142-4dd0-4351-8727-bd0977b6b2d1?CorrelationId=e9b85e57-7c0c-42d0-8bf3-c89d9f0faef6&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA101829163) and [Send an e-mail message based upon a template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Send-an-e-mail-message-based-upon-a-template-8d02e4e5-0ead-40f6-8285-366ee00f42e8)

Comment: I think it's not for the web version

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new email, down the bottom of the email window on the far right of the Send, Discard and various insert buttons there is a button with three dots "...". If you click that, you get a menu that has "My Templates" towards the bottom. When you click that you'll get a side bar on the right hand side of your screen and you can create and insert templates there.
It's more of a quick text than a true template, but it appears to be the closest thing available on the web interface.